# Apache output web page(layout) not properly

Tags: html, css, apache, twitter-bootstrap, centos

I install Apache on CentOS 7,

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

then copy [this](http://shapebootstrap.net/item/flat-theme-free-responsive-multipurpose-site-template/) webpage template to /var/www/html/

when I browse /var/www/html/index.html, I got this:

[image]

But I browse 127.0.0.1, I got this:

[image]

I tried on Chrome and IE, get the same output. The develop console output is the same.

Is my apache missing something ?

Comment: It seems to be a bug on CentOS 7 with Apache?
The web page works fine on Fedora and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your CSS or script paths are not correct/accessible (as long as this site does not require working PHP interpreter)...

Check what happens when you enter the address of CSS/Scripts location.

Comment: I can access all the CSS and Javascript file. 
There are no php in this template.

Comment: Well, that's odd then. I cannot find sources of the webpage to check what might be wrong here...

Comment: Oh, I post the worng link. You can download from here: http://shapebootstrap.net/item/flat-theme-free-responsive-multipurpose-site-template/

Comment: It's pure HTML indeed, I cannot think of anything but encoding/filesystem access permissions :| or apache bug...

Comment: "**sudo chmod +r /var/www/html/ -R**" I run this command, still can't fix the problem :|

Comment: Try to analyze Firefox's web console output of all the GET's when you refresh the page, that's all I can think of for now :(...